# How to get a file list from my own Google Drive and save it as a text file, with byte sizes?

Tags: list, file, download

So, I would like some button, or some command, or whatever that would produce a file list

Ideally, a CSV file, with the following fields

1. name
2. size in KB/MB
3. date

but I'd settle for a simple text file.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without code?

Comment: i hope there is no way.Explain what you need clearly...

Comment: sorry if this is an inappropiate question, but I'd like to either have batch file, or some sort of executable that I can run from the Run box in Windows, that will download the file list of all files on my Google drive. I would copy and paste them in a word doc, but there's noway to copy just the names.

Or, point me towards a program that I can feed some script to that can do this.